# how to get rid of body buffer overflow error 'protocol.http.TooBigBody' error while making api call?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, typescript, axios

I am doing axios GET call to fetch the data by passing date as param. For some specific dates, it is throwing 502 Bad gateway. Is there any way to resolve this error from client side like fetching the data in form of batches or it should be done something from the apigee or server side.

```
   "fault":{
      "faultstring":"Body buffer overflow",
      "detail":{
         "errorcode":"protocol.http.TooBigBody"
      }
   }
```